# Display tool tip on mouse hover of TableView

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any signal that of tableview that return the row over which the mouse is hovered over. I would like to display the contents of a cell in a tool tip when the mouse is over a certain row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in signal for that in the views, but instead the views support tooltips on items out-of-the-box if enabled in the model.

In your model, make sure to return the tooltip when it gets called with `Qt::ToolTipRole` in [data()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#data).

If you use `QStandardItemModel` instead of your own model, there are various ways to achieve the same. One example would be `QStandardItem::setToolTip()`, another is `QStandardItemModel::setItemData()`.

Comment: Does this mean I have to create my own model and inherit from the standard item model ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Edited my answer to also give some hints on what to do when you have a QStandardItemModel instead of your own custom model.

Comment: Thanks could you give me an example of how to return a tooltip from a QStandardItemModel using data() ? This sounds most feasable

Comment: If you use QStandarditemModel, overriding data() is actually not needed and too complicated. In your case, just call QStandardItem::setToolTip().